# Org external link - can I indicate which browser/tab to be used

Tags: org-mode, osx, tabs, hyperlinks, web-browser

Suppose I have several browsers running at any given time.

Google Chrome
Google Chrome Canary
Chromium
Opera
Safari

How can I indicate in my org mode links

```
[[https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/][GNU Emacs]]
```

which browser should be used when (C-c C-o) opening the link.

What I tried: Read https://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up your own protocols in `org-link-parameters` with `org-link-set-parameters`.

If you run

```el
(org-link-set-parameters "chrome" :follow (lambda (path) (browse-url-chrome (concat "http:" path))))
(org-link-set-parameters "chromes" :follow (lambda (path) (browse-url-chrome (concat "https:" path))))
(org-link-set-parameters "chromium" :follow (lambda (path) (browse-url-chromium (concat "http:" path))))
(org-link-set-parameters "chromiums" :follow (lambda (path) (browse-url-chromium (concat "https:" path))))
```

you can use `[[chrome://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/][GNU Emacs]]` or `[[chromes://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/][GNU Emacs]]` to open the link with the chrome browser `google-chrome`

and  `[[chromium://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/][GNU Emacs]]` or `[[chromiums://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/][GNU Emacs]]` to open the link with the chromium browser `chromium`.

If you want to choose between different `chrome` browsers I suggest you copy the function definition of `browse-url-chrome` from the library `browse-url`. Paste it into your init file, change the function name, and adapt the function to your purposes. Afterwards you can add link parameters for it.

You find the library `browse-url` easily with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd>... .

You can expand that solution to your likings. For an instance you can add an optional tab-number to the link if the `chrome` commando has such a parameter. You just have to process this information in your link handler. Note that the *link handlers* are the `lambda` expressions in the above example.